# how to code themes for linux?

Tags: ubuntu-8.10

i am using ubuntu , and the themes of firefox sucks .. so does the whole screen feel . I wish give it a os x theme and i know that there exists a MAC4lin to do that but i want to code it on my own .. how can i do it?

Comment: HOYGAN! Get a mac. Thank you beforearm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a bunch of theme information.

http://www.ubuntu-news.net/tag/themes/

and here is a link dealing specifically with creating a theme.

http://www.ubuntu-news.net/2009/07/07/ubuntu-gdm-theme-tutorial/

enjoy.